# python import behaviour: different objects from same file?

Tags: python, object, import, module

consider this:

```
/
test.py
lib/
L __init__.py
+ x/
  L __init__.py
  L p.py
```

with p.py:

```
class P():
    pass

p1 = P()
```

With test.py:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "lib"))

import lib.x.p
import x.p

print(id(lib.x.p.p1))
print(id(x.p.p1))
```

Here I get different object IDs though I am importing the same object from the same package/module Can someone please explain this behaviour, as it is very confusing, and I did not find any documentation about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Modules are cached in the dicitonary `sys.modules` using their dotted names as keys.  Since you are importing the same module by two different dotted names, you end up with two copies of this module, and also with two copies of everything inside them.

The solution is easy:  Don't do this, and try to avoid messing around with `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

`x.p` and `lib.x.p` aren't the same module. They come from the same file, but Python doesn't determine a module's identity by its file; a module's identity is based on its package-qualified name. The module search logic may have found the same file for both modules, but they're still loaded and executed separately, and objects created in one module are distinct from objects created in another.